# Given an SD card with Linux on it, how do you find out which platform and version it is?

Tags: linux, sd-card

I own a number of different platforms that use SD cards with Linux on them: Raspberry Pi, O-Droid, SabreLite, LS1021A, Panda, LattePanda...

I've found three SD cards, and reading them on a Linux PC I can see the filesystem. But I obviously can't execute `uname -a` - I haven't booted them, because I don't know what system to insert them in.

Can anyone suggest a reasonably reliable yet easy way to at the very least know which system they're for, if not which exact version they are? I'm hoping for a reasonably standard file I can access that will just happen to mention these crucial details.

I could well imagine that a per-system table would need to be set up:

- "For RPi, look [here]"
- "For SabreLite, look [here]"
- "For 1021A, look [here]"

But I'm hoping not!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually worked with anything besides RPi, but I would start with:

1. Find the kernel file (vmlinuz) – usually in the separate "boot" partition – and run `file` on it. It'll show roughly the same version information as uname would. (Which means, if it's just generic Raspbian, both will be equally useless.)
2. Look in the same "boot" partition for Device Tree data (*.dtb files). Convert them back to text format with `dtc -I dtb -O dts` and look for platform name in the 'compatible' field.
3. Look in the main filesystem's /var/log (possibly using `journalctl --directory=`). The early boot logs will have platform-related messages.

Comment: Ubuntu: option 1, `sudo file vmlinuz-...` shows kernel version and `16.04.1-Ubuntu`, option 2. no such files from `cd /boot && sudo find | grep dtb`, option 3. Hmm?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no multiple architectures are installed, there should be a directory in `/lib` named e.g. `x86_64-linux-gnu` or `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. So to get a hint regarding the architecture, this should work:

```
find <mountpoint>/lib -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*linux*'
```

The possible kernel versions are then listed in `/lib/modules` - you might just want to numerically sort them for getting the latest.

```
ls <mountpoint>/lib/modules | sort -rn | head -1
```

The OS name and version usually is named in `/etc/issue`.